# URANIUM UI Validations loosing its focus while typing

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, maui

I am following this [page](https://enisn-projects.io/docs/en/uranium/latest/themes/material/Validations) to add `URANIUM UI` Validations for my `MAUI 8.0` project. It displays a `TextField` as expected but while typing the name it is losing its focus.

I created a new project and added the necessary NuGet packages and here is my `XAML` code

```
xmlns:material="http://schemas.enisn-projects.io/dotnet/maui/uraniumui/material"
xmlns:validations="clr-namespace:InputKit.Shared.Validations;assembly=InputKit.Maui"

<material:TextField Title="Enter Name">
    <validations:MinLengthValidation MinLength="3" />
</material:TextField>
```

On typing first char it displays the error label **"The field should contain at least 3 characters"** and loses its focus on `TextFiled`. I manually need to click on `TextField` and then have to type another char. Now, on typing the third char, it clears the error label and again loses its focus on TextFiled so, I now again manually click on TextFiled to enter further characters.

I tried with `ValidationBinding` too but I see the same behavior.

```
Text="{v:ValidationBinding Form.Email, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Ever find how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, WinUI panels are focusable unlike other platforms. When a panel is focused it automatically delivers the focus event to its children recursively. It's even triggered when the layout is changed.

Here is a workaround for Windows:

```cs
public class MyTextField : TextField
{
#if WINDOWS
    protected override void RegisterForEvents()
    {
        base.RegisterForEvents();

        this.Unfocused += OnUnfocused;
    }

    protected override void ReleaseEvents()
    {
        base.ReleaseEvents();
        this.Unfocused -= OnUnfocused;
    }

    protected override void CheckAndShowValidations()
    {
        // Leave empty
    }

    private void OnUnfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        base.CheckAndShowValidations();
    }
#endif
}
```

```xml
<local:MyTextField />
```

Unfortunately, there is no active solution right now, I'll update here when a solution is applied.

It can be tracked from the original issue from here:
https://github.com/enisn/UraniumUI/issues/373#issuecomment-1893096078

Answer (score 0):

I have this also when running on Windows.  When running on Android Emulator, it works as expected.  I should clarify Windows 11 in case it makes a difference.